# Is it possible to clear the screen after grub boot selection?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9550 laptop alongside Windows 10. 
Unfortunately, the boot screen for windows boot manager only updates a very small portion of the screen (for a loading icon) which does not look good with the purple background of GRUB.  I would like to know if I can get GRUB to set the screen to black before the transition to windows boot manager.

Comment: are you using any customized grub theme or default one? you mean when you select windows boot manager option from grub and when you hit enter.. can you share a small video or pics to understand clearly..

Comment: I have not customized GRUB at all.  It looks something like this: https://imgur.com/ps9sKi1 (this is mock up in paint)

Comment: good mock up pic. seems its a different case, i am also dual booting Ubuntu18.04 with Win10 but when i hit enter a windows boot manager.. it acts as if Win10 is running like a single OS.. how much time is it taking for that windows boot animation.. black circle with white dots?

Comment: Very little time.  Windows boots in maybe 2 seconds?  I have an SSD so load times are incredible.

Comment: means, are you seeing that mock up pic only for 2 secs?

Comment: Pretty much.  I just shut down and booted back up to test and it was maybe 3 seconds at most.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87660/discussion-between-kingofgamesyami-and-pratap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing the background color of GRUB to black.

Answer (score 0):

These two other workarounds may also help fixing the Windows spinning dots when they are messing with the Grub background image (tested on Dell G3 3590 with Grub 2.04 and Windows 10 Home version 21H1):

#### Workaround 1 - Remove the Windows spinning dots

1. Boot Windows
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys to open the Run dialog
3. Enter command `msconfig`, then click OK
4. In the Boot tab, unselect the No GUI Boot option, then click OK
5. In the System Configuration dialog, click Restart to reboot

## Workaround 2 - Clear/replace the Grub background image (after grub boot selection)

1. In a terminal, enter these commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
   ```
2. Launch Grub Customizer
3. Right click the line with Windows Boot Manager, then select Edit
4. Select and copy the boot sequence, mine reads:

   ```
   savedefault
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod fat
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0AFF-E02B
   else
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0AFF-E02B
   fi
   chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
   ```
5. **Click Cancel to close the dialog without saving**
6. Click on the icon with the plus sign (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keys) to create a new menu entry
7. In the Entry editor dialog, enter Name **Windows 10 Home** (or any other suitable name)
8. Select Type **Other**
9. In Boot sequence, paste the copied lines from Step 4. **with 3 additional lines at the top** to clear the background image, mine reads:


   ```
   if background_image ; then
   clear
   fi
   ```

   ```
   savedefault
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod fat
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0AFF-E02B
   else
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0AFF-E02B
   fi
   chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
   ```

   **Remark:** Note that the path to a second image (displayed immediately after the user's choice) can be added between `background_image` and the semicolon `;`, for instance `if background_image /boot/grub/logo.png ; then`
10. Click OK to close the dialog
11. In the main Grub window, click Save
12. Reboot to run the newly created menu entry

**Remark:** I admit the 3 quick & dirty lines of code in Step 9. could have been improved. However, I have done enough try & fail research on a topic that is lacking well documented examples.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `GRUB_BACKGROUND=""` to `/etc/default/grub` and running `sudo update-grub` afterwards removed the background image (made it black) and also preserved the grub theme for the boot option selection screen.

Alternatively, you could add the value for `GRUB_BACKGROUND` via Grub Customizer under 'advanced settings'.

Changing the background color of GRUB to black (as suggested by KingofGamesYami) did not work for me, as I had a theme selected in Grub Customier.